# Why does VertexColors break Strikethrough?

Tags: graphics, bugs, style

#### Bug introduced in 12.3 and persisting through 14.0

---

`FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}` stops working when `VertexColors` is introduced.

Which versions affected?  What is a good work-around?

```
Graphics[{
  {LightGray, 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {0, 1}}
    , VertexColors -> Lighter /@ {Red, Green, Blue}]}, 
  Text[Style["Strike Through", 30, FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}]]
}]
```

> [image: graphic with missing strikethrough styling]

Comment out the VertexColors and it works as expected.

```
Graphics[{
  {LightGray, 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {0, 1}}
    (*, VertexColors -> Lighter /@ {Red, Green, Blue}*)]}, 
  Text[Style["Strike Through", 30, FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}]]
}]
```

> [image]

Comment: It works on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. `Graphics[{{LightGray, 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexColors -> Lighter /@ {Red, Green, Blue}]}, 
  Text[Style["Strike Through", 30, 
    FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}]]}]`

Comment: On `v13.2.1` I see the same as Mr.Wizard

Comment: @Syed I should have used that code so the example worked in versions before 13.1.  I am correcting it now.  Thank you.

Comment: Version 11.3,12.2  work, but Version 12.3,13.3.1,14.0 does not work.

Comment: It must be a bug since only `Text[Style["Strike Through", 30, 
  FontVariations -> {"Underlight" -> Black}]]` work for all of the version 11.3~ 14.0

Answer (score 2):

Does this count as a sufficiently good work-around??

```
Graphics[{{LightGray, 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {0, 1}}, 
     VertexColors -> Lighter /@ {Red, Green, Blue}]}}];
Graphics[
  Text[Style["Mr Wizard", 30, 
    FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}]]];
Overlay[{%%, %}]
```

> [image: wizard]

Edit: The above suggestions also works with [`Struckthrough`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Struckthrough.html) that was in version 1 of Mr. Wizard's question. I am just stupid and missed it.

```
Graphics[{{LightGray, 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {0, 1}}, 
     VertexColors -> Lighter /@ {Red, Green, Blue}]}}];
Graphics[Text[Style["Mr Wizard", 30, Struckthrough]]];
Overlay[{%%, %}]
```

Comment: `Struckthrough` is just a convenience alias.  I am sorry that I introduced that obfuscation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard not your fault, it was my bad.  I think that turning everything into `Graphics` and using `Overlay` should be a stable work-around. Also, since this is not the same behaviour as in older versions, maybe we could add the bugs tag and header?